# How to get rid of the error in this SWIG file

Tags: python, swig

I have the following SWIG file downloaded from this website, which provides a c++ code to calculate visibility polygons. I want to be able to call this from Python. Note the name of the package is spelled weirdly as 
"visilibity" and not "visibility".

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 using Swig 2.0 and using  Python 2.7

I tried using the command `swig -python visilibity.i` on the SWIG file below and got the error at the bash prompt.

`/usr/share/swig2.0/python/std_common.i:73: Error: Syntax error in input(1).`

I am clueless as to what is wrong here. I have made sure that the header files and the .cpp files are in the same directory as the .i file.

```
%module visilibity
%{
#include "visilibity.hpp"
%}

%include std_vector.i
namespace std {
      %template(pointList) vector<VisiLibity::Point>;
      %template(polygonList) vector<VisiLibity::Polygon>;
}


%include visilibity.hpp


%extend VisiLibity::Polygon {
  Point __getitem__(unsigned i) {
    return (*self)[i];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's C++ code, so you need to tell this to swig:

```
swig -c++ -python visilibity.i
```